# How casting negative number to wider type works inside?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Suppose, you have

```
short num = -10;
int num_casted = (int)num;
std::cout << num_casted << endl; // prints -10.
```

I wonder, why `num_casted` is still `-10` and not `0xFA000000`.

How negative number of smaller type converted to biggen one ? Will anyone enlighten me ? I assume there is some logic behind except padding free space with zeros...

Comment: It's the least surprising way, really. `num` has the value -10, so `num_casted` is the `int` representation of -10.

Comment: [Sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). This is a value conversion, not a bit reinterpretation, so the work is done for you to retrieve a coherent `-10` instead of shifted garbage.

Comment: If you convert into a larger type of same signedness, then that larger type can necessarily represent the same value, so it is converted to the representation that has the same value.

Comment: in binary code. What happens inside ? It is not simply adding missing zeroes... Otherwise we would get the result as in my question...

Comment: @IgorTarlinskii what happens "inside" depends on what you are inside of. More specifically, how are negative numbers represented by the CPU that you're asking about?

Comment: @Quentin, who is doing the work for me ? Compiler ?

Comment: Yes, it is adding zeros. But it is adding them to the *most significant* end of the value, as opposed to the *least significant* end of the value (which, honestly, would make absolutely no sense). Since these are signed types, it adds zeros in such a way as to compensate for the sign bit (assuming a two's-complement representation). What aspect of your question does the above-linked Wikipedia article not answer adequately? Yes, the compiler generates the necessary code to make this happen. That code will be one or more machine-code instructions that cause the CPU to do the bit manipulation.

Comment: @IgorTarlinskii someone between your compiler and your CPU (inclusive, inclusive), depending on your platform. I'm no assembly coder, but I expect modern CPUs to have sign-extension instructions.

Comment: [2's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) is more or less universally used to represent negative numbers. But to my knowledge that isn't required by the standard, so this isn't really a C++ question, this is more of an implementation or compiler question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming x86/x86-64 architecture with 2C number representation.

For signed numbers missing bits are filled with sign bit (last bit of converted value). For unsigned numbers missing bits are filled with zero-s.

Signed conversion is compiled to `movsx` instruction (mov with sign extension), and unsigned conversion with `movzx` (mov with zero extension). Probably there are several variants of these instructions (for different argument size, for integer math on SSE, for integer math on AVX2 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

When you cast to a larger integer type, you *should* keep the same value. It wouldn't be sensible to do otherwise. I believe the standard guarantees this.

In two's complement, it's very easy to make a number a wider type while keeping the same value and sign - you simply fill the new upper bits with the same value the sign bit had originally. For positive numbers you zero fill, and for negative numbers you one fill.